# enviar array como paramentros a procedimiento almacenado desde c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

que al amigo estoy haciendo una consulta dinamica, dentro de u procedimiento almacenado, para ello los datos de entrada los tomo de unos elementos select2 que envio por aja, hasta aqui no hay problema, el problema empieza cuando quiero pasar dichos parámetros al procedimiento almacenado. para lo cual ocupo lo siguiente.

en el controlador

```
public ActionResult ResumenProcedimientos2(string[] itemLicitaciones, string[] itemTipoEventos, int? Ejercicio)
    {
        var connectionStringsql = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringsql);

        Response oResponse = new Response();

        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[MtoProcedimiento.Resumen.Contratos]"))
            {

                try
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter;
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ListProcedimientos", itemLicitaciones);
                    connection.Open();                         
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    adapter.Fill(ds);
                
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    oResponse.succeeded = false;
                    oResponse.Message = ex.Message;
                    return Json(oResponse, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
            oResponse.succeeded = true;
            return Json(oResponse, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            Exception raise = dbEx;
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);

                    raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                }
            }
            oResponse.succeeded = false;
            oResponse.Message = raise.Message;
            return Json(oResponse, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

ahora el codigo del procedimiento almacenado es:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MtoProcedimiento.Resumen.Contratos]
    
     @Ejercicio as Int,
     @ListProcedimientos as VARCHAR(MAX),
     @MtoCaracterId as VARCHAR(MAX),
     @MtoTipoEventoId as VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Query AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
         
 SET @Query=N'select a.Ejercicio,a.MtoProcedimientoId,a.NoLicitacion,
            b.MtoTipoEventoId,b.Descripcion, 
            d.MtocaracterId,d.Descripcion,
            e.MtoTipoCompraId,e.Descripcion,
            COUNT(distinct NoContrato) as Nocontratos,
            sum(distinct c.MontoContrato) as MoncoContrato
            from MtoProcedimiento a
            left join MtoTipoEvento B ON b.MtoTipoEventoId=a.MtoTipoEventoId
            left join MtoContrato c on c.MtoProcedimientoId=a.MtoProcedimientoId
            left join MtoCaracter d on a.MtoCaracterId=d.MtoCaracterId
            left join MtoTipoCompra e on e.MtoTipoCompraId=a.MtoTipoCompraId
            group by
            a.Ejercicio,a.MtoProcedimientoId,a.NoLicitacion,
            b.MtoTipoEventoId,b.Descripcion, 
            d.MtocaracterId,d.Descripcion,
            e.MtoTipoCompraId,e.Descripcion
            having a.MtoprocedimientoId>0';
        
     IF @ListProcedimientos IS NOT NULL 
      BEGIN 
       
       SET @Query= @Query + ' AND a.MtoProcedimientoId in (' + @ListProcedimientos +')'   
      END 
   
     /*IF @Ejercicio>0
      BEGIN 
       SET @Query = @Query + ' AND a.Ejercicio =' +CAST(@Ejercicio,int)     
      END */
  
     IF @MtoCaracterId IS NOT NULL 
      BEGIN 
       SET @Query = @Query + ' AND a.MtoTipoEventoId in (' + @MtoCaracterId +')'    
      END 
   
     IF @MtoTipoEventoId IS NOT NULL 
      BEGIN 
       SET @Query = @Query + ' AND a.MtoTipoEventoId in (' + @MtoTipoEventoId +')'
      END 
   
    PRINT @Query 
    

     EXECUTE sp_executesql  @Query 

END
```

el error que me manda es el siguiente

```
No hay ninguna asignación de tipo de objeto System.String[] a un tipo nativo de un proveedor administrado conocido.
```

podrian por favor darme una idea como pasos esos parametros al procedimiento almacenado.

muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Se usa los

[Table-Valued Parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters) que solo estan diponibles desde la version de SQL Server 2008

entonces podras pasar una lista de valores por parametro al procedure

Pero vas a tener que crear un tipo definido en sql server, inficando este en el parametro de tipo `SqlDbType.Structured`

```
SqlParameter tvpParam = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombreparam", datos);  
tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;  
tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.NombreType";
```